# ERROR: error 3002: Issue in mapping fragments starting at line 6 -runtime violation of table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

**DETAILED ERROR:**  Message    "\r\nPOLLINATOR.msl(6,10) : error 3002: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 6:Potential runtime violation of table BENEFIT's keys (BENEFIT.BENEFIT_ID): Columns (BENEFIT.BENEFIT_ID) are mapped to EntitySet BENEFITs's properties (BENEFITs.BENEFIT_ID) on the conceptual side but they do not form the EntitySet's key properties (BENEFITs.BENEFIT_ID, BENEFITs.PLANT_ID).\r\n"

I am doing a LINQ query on a table BEE that has no references to any other tables and definitely not to the BENEFIT table.  However, I am getting this error:

This is my SELECT:

```
public List<BEE> getBeeSearchResult()
{
    List<BEE> result = null;
    try
    {
        result = (from BEE in db.BEEs
                            orderby BEE.BEE_NAME ascending
                            select BEE).ToList();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        String msg = "Error getting details: " + ex.InnerException;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had a problem with a constraint in the BENEFIT table and fixing that resolved the issue.